# How to create an Azure API App using the .YAML file and Python code?

Tags: python, azure, yaml, azure-api-apps

One of my clients wants to host his API's in Azure, his APIs are developed in Python. I tried creating Azure API app in dot net and I am getting the successful result but I don't have any knowledge of Python, can anyone help me finding out how can I host these python API's in Azure?

The source file has a .YAML file, some .py file and some .html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm to your customer, whether the Python APIs are in a complete Python web application.

There are several most popular python web frameworks your customer may use to build the APIs server, Flask, Django and Bottle. You can find the document about how to deploy these application to Azure Web Apps at [Creating web apps with Flask in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app/), [Creating web apps with Django in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/) and [Creating web apps with Bottle in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-bottle-app/).

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Should one use one of these frameworks if your web front end is in React and you need it to then call a Python API? (i.e. the Python api does not need to worry about a web front end)

Comment: Is your front end application is a pure SPA?